# how to combine logs coming from multiple virtual machines for processing?

Tags: programming-practices, networking, distributed-computing, virtual-machine

Scenario:

Two virtual machines produce logs. I want these logs to be sent to a central server for processing (as soon as a line of these logs is generated-->streaming ). The condition here is that I want the server to know from which virtual machine the log line came from. In the server, we should observe a file containing something like:

action 1 happended in VM1 
action 2 happended in VM1 
action 1 happended in VM2
action 3 happended in VM1
action 2 happended in VM2

Question: 
How can such a thing be implemented in an efficient way? How can streaming to a central server be done? I hope the question is clear..

Comment: What tools do you have? bash? java? node.js? This may be done in a myriad ways, so please narrow your question down.

Comment: I feel like this should go to serverfault.